# List of Top Repositories by Programming Language

Tags: programming-languages, repository

One of the main reasons I like Perl is [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) (Comprehensive Perl Archive Network) is the ease of finding, installing, and testing of packages it provides that solve a problem I was already trying to solve. I would like to know of any similar repositories for PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, C++, Javascript, etc..., or better, a comprehensive list of such repositories. What are the top repositories you go to for the languages you  program in, or what repositories do you use to share your code?

The list from the comments so far is:

- C++: [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)
- Haskell: [HackageDB](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hackage.html)
- Java: [Maven](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) and [SpringSource](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/)
- JavaScript: [Scripteka](http://scripteka.com/) and [JSAN](http://openjsan.org/)
- Lua: [LuaForge](http://luaforge.net/) and [LuaRocks](http://www.luarocks.org/en)
- OCaml: [GODI](http://godi.camlcity.org/godi/index.html)
- PHP: [Pear](http://pear.php.net/) and [Pecl](http://pecl.php.net/)
- Perl: [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org)
- Python: [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)
- R: [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/)
- Ruby: [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/)
- TeX, LaTex: [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/)

Comment: If it's not CW, the question usually tends to get closed.

Answer (score 10):

[CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) (Comprehensive R Archive Network) is the package repository for the [R](http://www.r-project.org/) language/environment with 68 mirrors and >2000 extension packages.

Comment: CRAN is actually peer-reviewed (actually gatekeeper-reviewed) too, somewhat like Boost.  I wish it weren't, but the submission process is actually "send an email to the CRAN gatekeepers" and await approval.  Approval (or denial) usually comes swiftly, but IMO it would be much better to take the gatekeeper out of the mix, like CPAN does.

Answer (score 6):

[Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org) is the package repository for Haskell. along with it's cabal tool makes package finding / building quite easy.

Answer (score 4):

[boost](http://www.boost.org) is a set of peer reviewed C++ packages. It's no where near as large as CPAN, but it's still a repository for C++.

Comment: That's not really the same thing. It's not an open community extension system. It's collection of pre-defined packages. Not that it's not great and really useful, just not the same thing.

Comment: The original quetion was about a community repository of software. Boost can be contributed to by anyone in the community and is freely available. The only difference is the software is peer reviewed. Still seems to fit the bill to me.

Comment: it falls smack on the borderline to me. the code is very useful, but the bar to entry is quite high. it would be great if they had a "contender" category to submit code into that could be vetted by the community more within the open source model. that said, i haven't found any other such C++ or C repositories.

Comment: @jeff: I'll agree, the community vetting process is significantly different than CPAN with a much higher barrier to entry, but the question only asked for community repositories, not community repositories with a specific contribution policy.

Answer (score 3):

For PHP there is [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) for components and [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/) for extensions. Both of them proved to be useful more than once to me.

Answer (score 3):

For those who consider TeX and LaTeX programming languages, there's the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network - [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/)

Answer (score 3):

OCaml has [GODI](http://godi.camlcity.org).

Answer (score 2):

For java people, there's the Maven [Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) repo, and also [Sonatype's mirror](http://repository.sonatype.org/index.html) of most public repos.

If you want OSGi-ified, bundles, there's the [Spring EBR](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/).

Answer (score 1):

There's [LuaForge](http://luaforge.net/) for... uh... Lua, I think.

There's also [LuaRocks](http://www.luarocks.org/) which is aiming to make a more-or-less equivalent to Python's `easy_install`.

Answer (score 1):

[JSAN](http://openjsan.org) is a JavaScript repository inspired by CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

[Scripteka](http://scripteka.com/) is an open repository of extensions to the Prototype Javascript framework. Much more niche than just a language library repository, but still in the same vein.

Answer (score 1):

- C: [C code archive](http://ccodearchive.net/)
- Chicken Scheme: [Eggs Unlimited](http://wiki.call-cc.org/chicken-projects/egg-index-4.html)
- Common Lisp: [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org), [asdf](http://www.cliki.net/asdf)
- Erlang: [CEAN](http://cean.process-one.net/), [Agner](http://erlagner.org/)
- Forth: [: the Forth net ;](http://theforth.net/)
- Node.js: [npm](http://npmjs.com/)
- OCaml: [The Hump](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.cgi)

Answer (score 1):

In the OCaml world, [opam](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/) seems to be gaining momentum very rapidly. I personally already find it easier to work with than GODI, and have made the switch.

Ruby has [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/) now, which has superseded rubyforge.

Answer (score 0):

If we speak about simple cookbook examples you can think about this one: [Pleac](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I don't think this is what he had in mind. I think he was refering to actual code packages.

Answer (score -3):

You could consider [github](http://github.com/) a mostly Ruby repository, in it's current state.

Comment: That's kind of like saying sourceforge is a mostly PHP repository. Sure the majority of projects listed there are PHP, but it's not really the same thing.